# Python TrippleDes

Tags: python, 3des

I took a job here at the company to decrypt an encrypted password that comes in Tripple Des.

goodnight

I have no knowledge in Tripple Des so I need help decrypting a key.

I have a script in my documentation:

Script to decrypt PINBlock ISO Format 0 3DES

Data:

PINBLOCK 3DES = C9C4D04C21FC618F – ENCRYPTED PASSWORD.

Card with 16 positions: 1234567890123456
PAN will be the last 12 positions excluding the last character and with leading zeros.
PAN: 0000456789012345 – 16 positions.

ZPK = 6B43C8417C9270F00DCED51EDDE68E11 – EXAMPLE - MASTER KEY

1 - Decrypt the data:

PinBlock in Claro = 0412719876FEDCBA

2 – XOR of the PINBlock with the formed PAN.

```
0412719876FEDCBA
XOR
0000456789012345
=
041234FFFFFFFFFF – Password 1234.
```

I use python and installed the libraries

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

from pyDes import *
```

I followed some examples and tutorials but I didn't advance.

can anybody help me?

Answer (score -3):

This a very broad question, but all your answers should be available in this excellent article and tutorial here: https://developer.mastercard.com/card-issuance/documentation/pin-block-encryption-process/ with code samples and explanations.

If you run into specific problems at some specific stage ask again about your particular issue then.

Comment: Could I please ask for a brief explanation of why the down votes? It will help me improve answers in the future, and I can perhaps fix this one as well.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. If the links break, this answer is meaningless, s. [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231).